# function $f(x)=x^x\cdot e^x$, an asymptote solution for $f(n)=x_n$

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series

$f\colon(1,\infty)\to\mathbb{R}$ defined as $f(x)=x^x\cdot e^x$ is continuous und strictly increasing, so for every $n$ there ist exactly one $x_n$ suth that $f(x_n)=n$, but it is not possible to solve the equation und write $x_n$ derectly.
How can be found an asymptote $y_n$? (a sequence $y_n$ suth that it can be written by formula und it satisfy $\lim\frac{x_n}{y_n}=1$)

Comment: You defined $x_n=f(n)$, so why do you think you can't write $x_n=(ne)^n$? Or did you mean by any chance $f(x_n)=n$?

Comment: $f(x_n)=n$, I'm sorry for the mistake

Comment: Why must an asymptote exist?